# what is possible flow for charge defect formation energy and how to plot charge defect FE vs fermi energy

Tags: density-functional-theory

HOW TO CALCULATE ALL PARAMETERS FOR CHARGE DEFECT FORMATION ENERGY USING VASP, Possible workflow for Practical Calculation
How to draw the plot of Formation energy v Fermi energy like this.
[image]

Comment: As written, it is not clear what you are asking. Please take some time to edit your question to make it clear to potential answers what problem you are having and how you have attempted to solve it.

Comment: Check out pydefect (https://kumagai-group.github.io/pydefect/), spinney (https://spinney.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html), or other similar codes.

Comment: Thank you very much, CW Tan. I have already installed these codes, but unfortunately, I am unclear about how to use PyDefect. Could you provide any insight into how to start?